# How to fixed element in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a flatlist that shows my restaurant foods. and I have a buy basket that shows the count and total cost of foods. Now I want to know how can I fixed the position of the basket buy on the flat list.

Note: The buy basket on the flat list is a little icon that shows the count and total cost of foods.

Thanks advance.

Comment: is css not working?

Comment: i think you should put **buy basket** outside FlatList if you want it to be fixed. also as @PriyeshKumar suggests uou can use style={{position: 'absolute'}}

Comment: It's easier to help if you post sample code, and maybe some images about what your current problem is and what it should look like. Sometimes you are missing something simple in your code, or something that's hard to find or to try. Usually the community here works faster if you provide this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for Floating Action Button like a solution with Flatlist like below example image, find the [full code here](https://ajmalpkc.gitbook.io/floating-action-button-with-flatlist/).

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZJ3e.jpg)

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => <View style={styles.list}>
  <Text>Name : {item.name}</Text>
  <Text>Age : {item.age}</Text>
  </View>}
/>

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert('FAB clicked')} 
 style={{
 position: 'absolute',
 width: 56,
 height: 56,
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
 right: 20,
 bottom: 20,
 backgroundColor: '#03A9F4',
 borderRadius: 30,
 elevation: 8
 }}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 40,color: 'white'}}>+</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this:

```
//MyComponent.js

import { FlatList, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default class MyComponent extends Component {
    renderFlatlist() {
        return <FlatList data={...} />;
    }

    renderBasket() {
        return (
            <View>
                //Your basket
            </View>
        );
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <ScrollView>
                    {this.renderFlatlist()}
                </ScrollView>
                <View>
                    {this.renderBasket()}
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```